# QGIS Map Tips Table, style every other row

Tags: qgis, html, css, maptips

I simply want to style every other row in a table I've generated using map tips with a different coloured background. I've got the correct generic CSS (I think) but nothing is changing.

```
tr:nth-child (odd) {
background:grey!important;
}
```

Below is the CSS styling for the table, I feel the contents of the table is irrelevant to show as code but I have shown an image below.

```
<style> 

body { 
background-color: white!important; 
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 200px;
} 

table { 
border-collapse: collapse; 
} 

th { 
font-size: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 10px;
background: grey;
color: white;
}

tr { 
border: 2px solid white; 
} 

tr:nth-child (odd) {
background:grey!important;
}

td { 
font-size: 12px;
white-space: nowrap; 
padding: 5px; 
}

td.h2{
font-size: 15px; 
float: left!important;
font-weight: bold;
background:grey;
}

td.bold { 
font-size: 12px; 
font-weight: bold; 
} 

td.gap { 
background-color:white; 
padding:1px; 
} 

</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your style,only need add:

> .table tr:nth-child(odd){  background: #b8d1f3; }
>
> .table tr:nth-child(even){ background: #dae5f4; }

And put your table class when create the table,for example:

```
    <style> 

        body { 
        background-color: white!important; 
        font-family: sans-serif;
        width: 200px;
        } 

        table { 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        } 

        th { 
        font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px;
        background: grey;
        color: white;
        }

        tr { 
        border: 2px solid white; 
        } 

        tr:nth-child (odd) {
        background:grey!important;
        }

        td { 
        font-size: 12px;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        padding: 5px; 
        }

        td.h2{
        font-size: 15px; 
        float: left!important;
        font-weight: bold;
        background:grey;
        }

        td.bold { 
        font-size: 12px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        } 

        td.gap { 
        background-color:white; 
        padding:1px; 
        } 
        .table tr:nth-child(odd){ 
        background: #b8d1f3;
        }

        .table tr:nth-child(even){
        background: #dae5f4;
        }

    </style>

    <table class="table">
        <th><h1>Alternating Table Rows</h1></th>

    <tr><td class="bold">Name:</td><td>[% "NAME" %] </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="bold">Use:</td><td> [% "USE" %] </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="bold">Elevation:</td><td>[% "ELEV" %]</td></tr>
</table>
```

And the result is:

[image]